# setting up intent that looks for a variable

Tags: android, android-intent

I know very little about Android, so pardon if this question isn't asked properly.

I'm trying to setup an intent that opens my app when a url is selected.. my code looks like the:

```
        <intent-filter> 
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="something.com" android:pathPattern=".*p=.*" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

and it works perfectly - but I want to only launch the app if there is a variable "p" in the URL. Meaning: do not launch http://something.com/ok    but launch http://something.com/ok/?p=100

I'm thinking I need to add the android:pathPattern attribute and look for "p="? can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use the `pathPattern` attribute of an intent filter.  [(See the reference here.)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#path)

Comment: awesome, glad I'm on the right path. Any hints on what the pattern should look like?

Comment: Please read the docs, they give examples, it will probably be something like *p=* or something similar...

Comment: that should have been star p= star

Comment: thanks, yeah I've tried all of that and read the docs. I've tried every permutation of android:pathPattern="*\\test\\*" except for the right one :)

Comment: Crudola, what seems to be sticking you up now?